# How can I backup NDS .sav files to my computer?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-ds, pokemon-fourth-generation, nintendo-dsi

I'm looking to extract the .sav files of certain NDS games (Pokemon Diamond, Pokemon Platinum, Pokemon Ranger, LOZ: Phantom Hourglass, LOZ: Spirit Tracks, and a few others) for which I'm using the official cartridges. I'm doing this so that I have a backup in case any of the games gets corrupted in the future, as I have put in hundreds of hours into these games. I have the following:

- Nintendo 3DS
- Nintendo DSi
- Nintendo DS Lite
- Official game cartridges
- R4 (with the microSD and the ability to copy data to/from the computer)
- Mac and Windows laptops (primarily use Mac)

Is there any way I can manage this without installing unofficial software onto any of the devices or purchasing additional hardware? (If that is not the case, what additional hardware would be recommended? I have heard of the NDS Adaptor Plus and the Action Replay, although I don't know how good they are.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. Save files for pokemon games are stored on the cartridge.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, use TWL save tool on your 3ds to backup those games. Here a link for you: https://gbatemp.net/threads/release-twlsavetool-v1-0.412887/